# Setting scale in Preview

Tags: preview

In Preview, images sometimes open at 21% scale, sometimes at 80% scale, etc... I just want to fix the scale at 100% for all image files. How to do this in Preview ? I can't find any answer...

Answer (score -1):

Preview's Preferences has an option for how '100%' scale is defined, for both images and PDFs (separately).

You can either choose '1 image pixel equals 1 screen pixel'; or 'Size on screen equals size on printout'.

Because images have a resolution value defined in metadata, the number of pixels per inch (or centimetre!) can vary. Thus one image could appear to be 'larger' on the screen for the same number of pixels (with the second option chosen).

Comment: My point is : how to set to 100% the scale parameter of all image files ? I have already seen the information you give, but may be this simple setting I'm looking for is no longer available in Preview...
Look, it means that if you have a lot of images with different scales, you have to adjust this scale parameter with each file ! Kind of crazy isn't it ?
Cheers and thank's.
Daniel.